# OpenERP - connections to database

Tags: postgresql, odoo, pgadmin

I am running OpenERP v6, Windows, PostgreSQL 9.1. When I connect to the database from my Windows OpenERP client, the OpenERP service makes a connection to database. This connection is visible in pgAdmin Server Status window. When I close OpenERP client, the connection is still there. Moreover, if I open OpenERP Client again, then login, the OpenERP service creates another connection to database, visible in Server Status window. Should there be only one connection to database made by OpenERP service for multiple OpenERP Clients? Can someone clarify to me the logic behind the OpenERP connectivity to database? Can this be a bug in the server code? If yes, can you direct to web site where the bug is fixed or to the file name where the relevant code is? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can run multiple Openerp Server With PostgresSQL 9.1 with changing the port number

You can change the port number by following way:

```
./openerp-server --xmlrpc-port=8070 --db-filter=your_database_name
```

You can also manually kill the process which is running on current port number